# Mac won't accept SSH traffic despite being set to allow remote access to all users

Tags: terminal, network, unix, ssh

I am trying to `ssh -v user_name@host_address` from Linux to a Mac and I get this output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017 debug1: Reading 
configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: 
Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to host_address [host_address] 
port 22.
```

...and then it times out.

On my Mac, my sshd-keygen-wrappers have full access, my Firewall is set to allow all incoming SSH connections, and remote access to all users is enabled as well.

What am I missing here?

Comment: That looks to be a problem on the Linux end (if it was the Mac it would reference `sshd_config` as the Mac is running the server daemon).  Can you successfully SSH to other computers using your Linux machine?  What does line 58 of your `ssh_config` say?

Comment: if you just 'telnet' to port 22 on the suspect host, do you get a sign-on from the `sshd`?